# How to save fragment's backstack into the file?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to get all fragment backastack entries with:
`getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(index);`

Than i need to save it into file and restore it from file.
I've tried to add it to back stack:
`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(index).getName()).commit();`

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Use this project on github https://github.com/iamjayanth/FragmentTabStudy

Comment: Gtreat! Thats it!!! Thanks a lot :)